Need help to find movie involving another dimension
It is about a man who figure that a family member's secret after he gets there. He will find another dimension when he uses a watch or something and falls in love with another girl from that dimension.                                 
He finds a building at the end to sleep or lay at rest to be with the girl from Another Dimension.   
It sets off in the late 1800s-1900s. And the guy basically is a god in the dimension and stops the invasion of the womans world.
I dont know what year it was made. I believe 2006-2014 the movie was made.

Found it. It was john carter

"Found it." Better to either write up an answer (n.b. not a comment), or delete the question.

@andrew that's not how it works here...

John Carter of Mars.
The Family member is his nephew, whom John used as bait. There is no watch, it's an alien teleporter device. The building is a masuleum that John had built, to protect his body while he teleport to Mars again, since the teleportation is making a remote copy. A copy that's super human due to the lower gravity of Mars compared to Earth. Muscle density.
